# How do I set a maximum of words in a string to display in processing?

Tags: java, arrays, text, processing

At the moment I've two strings with 5 words in each of them. Each will resemble a certain language at some point. What I don't want is an infinite of words on my screen, I only want like 50 of each language. How do I set a maximum value of 50 to the words in the string?

This is the current code:

```
int alpha = 1, delta = 1;
String [] wordsArabic = {
  "Chicken", "Mc", "Nugget", "Kippetje", "Lekker"
};

String [] wordsDutch = {
  "Vluchten", "Taal", "Nederlands", "Syrie", "Land"
};

void setup(){
  size( 1080, 1080);
  smooth();
  filter( THRESHOLD, 0.9);
  ellipseMode(CENTER);
}

void draw(){
  color(0, 0, 0);
  if (alpha == 0 || alpha == 255) { delta = -delta; }
  alpha += delta;
  fill( random(255), random(255), random(255), alpha);
  noStroke();
  textSize(random(10,30));
  text(wordsArabic [int (random(5))], random(height), random(width));
  text(wordsDutch [int (random(5))], random(height), random(width));
}
```

Comment: You should tag the specific language as well to get better response

Comment: what is the programming language that you are trying to use?

Comment: Sorry it’s in Java :)

Comment: Use a [for](https://processing.org/reference/for.html) loop to iterate 50 times and cycle through the words you need. Bare in mind you're not clearing the buffer, so words will keep being drawn on screen continuously.

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza How would I use the for loop in my code? I wanted to use this:   for(int i=0; i <2; i++){} but that's only for an interger.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want 50 for each language, you should use a `for` loop in your code.

This loop will repeat the code inside 50 times:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  // pick one word from the language and display it 
}
```

You need to understand that Processing **calls the draw() method repeatedly**.

Since you are picking the words randomly and Processing calls the `draw()` method repeatedly, you cannot put a `for` loop in `draw()` else it will endlessly call the `for` loop and repeat it indefinitely. I would personally put all the code that you have in `draw()` into `setup()`.

Another suggestion to organize your code is that you should write it as a method to display the words.
Here is a layout of what I would do:

```
void displayWords(String[] language) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      // pick one word from the language and display it 
    }
}
```

Then you can easily just call `displayWords(wordsArabic)` or `displayWords(wordsDutch)`.

I hope this answers your question, good luck!